# Is there a way add auto completion support for Java to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: java, sublimetext

is there a way to add auto-completion support for Java functions and libraries to Sublime Text 2, like Eclipse has?

Comment: for example http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/search.php?fid[]=4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try out my plugin: Display-Functions (Java).  It adds function autocompletion for files in the current directory.  It's pretty powerful, too.  I have debated adding support for `import` but have not seen a high enough demand.  If that's important though, let me know.

You can install it through Package Control or from Github: https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions

Comment: thanks i installed it via package control. it works with my classes but it wont work with for example when i import java.util.*

Comment: Yeah, I've considered adding support for `import <something>` but (a) Haven't gotta around to it (b) want to keep it fast and lightweight (c) haven't had enough people request it to prompt me to do it.  If I get some time later, I'll check it out and see what I can do.

Comment: Hey BoundinCode, I would love to use it but can not get it running. I made all .class files available. I have the newest version and a clean maven java project. I am opening the project root. I see all .class files within sublime. Thx a lot for you help in advance! I have MacOS

Comment: @Denis Display-Functions isn't very smart, so it requires looking at the actual java files. So unless it's a small personal project, my plugin can't really help. I do recommend you give SublimeJava a try, though (https://github.com/quarnster/sublimejava).

Comment: Is something similar available for ST3?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with SublimeJava plugin https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeJava/ though it didn't work as expected for me.

I found that it couldn't properly complete methods from classes of my own project when triggering completion on an instanciated object.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo. // didn't trigger autocompletion popup even though imports where in place
```

also I'd rather have functionality to automatically add imports. SublimeJava doesn't provide this. Also I found it rather slow in my particular case.

You can also try Subclim https://github.com/JulianEberius/Subclim which provides integration with eclim. The problem here is that you need Eclipse running (eclimd didn's worked properly for me).

By the way, I tried all these configurations running Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7 OS.