# Integrate SubLime with my javadoc

Tags: java, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have developed my own java API's, with complex signatures, I am trying to find a way for Sublime to recognize the javadoc so that autocomplete works for my API's.

I have searched, and instead found questions that help develop javadoc, not use them with autocomplete. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

Comment: What does Javadoc have to do with it? Anything that did this correctly would operate directly on the method signatures themselves, which are the ultimate truth of your code, and iff Javadoc info was available, show that as well. In any case, there's JavaIME, for whatever it's worth. The bottom line is that you'll never get real Java IDE features out of Sublime.

Comment: Also, if the code is in your project, and you have any of the various completion packages installed, you'll get project-wide completion suggestions anyway.

Comment: Thats sad, I was hoping to use sublime with autocomplete and compilation errors during developing like a regular IDE. Please post an answer.

Comment: Just to emphasize what Dave Newton has said: Javadoc and IDE autocomplete have nothing to do with one another. Also, if you want Java to autocomplete in Sublime, then you should Google "java sublime autocomplete" and try the solutions you find there. If the solutions do not work for you, then post a question here explaining exactly why. As is, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way add auto completion support for Java to Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369617/is-there-a-way-add-auto-completion-support-for-java-to-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Thanks.. seems like a duplicate.. I'll evaluate the answer and update the question or mark it duplicate.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

> I was hoping to use sublime with autocomplete and compilation errors during developing like a regular IDE.

Seems for python there is something like it.

[image]

> Anaconda turns your Sublime Text 3 in a full featured Python development IDE including autocompletion, code linting, IDE features, autopep8 formating, McCabe complexity checker Vagrant and Docker support for Sublime Text 3 using Jedi, PyFlakes, pep8, MyPy, PyLint, pep257 and McCabe that will never freeze your Sublime Text 3.
>   
>   https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda

The `Anaconda` can be also extended to other languages.

> Would you like to see your language empowered by anaconda? Use anaconda_rust or anaconda_php as templates and bring your language to life with anaconda's plugable architecture.
>   
>   https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda#available-plugins-for-anaconda